# How to handle dot character in Rails resources routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to have SEO optimized urls like this

```
http://example.com/sites/1-blau.de/plans
```

But the dot in the path cause Rails to chock. How do I escape dots to percentage notation form so it can work?

My routes:

```
resources :sites, only: [] do
  resources :plans, only: [:index, :show] do
  end
end
```

I have tried URI.escape and CGI.escape, neither worked.

```
URI.escape('a.b')=> "a.b"
CGI.escape('a.b')=> "a.b"
```

What I thought I wanted

```
Foo.escape('a.b')=> "a%2Eb"
```

Comment: Have you tried `backslash \\`?

Comment: @Bala what do you mean?

Comment: I think he means `\.`

Comment: Foe me `URI.escape` is working fine.`enc_uri = URI.escape("http://example.com/sites/1-blau.de/plans")`
 `=> "http://example.com/sites/1-blau.de/plans"`

Comment: I realized even if I escape it by hand (convert period mark to "%2E") it wouldn't work, because browser will convert it automatically back to period.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a constraint that accepts dot character.

```
get 'sites/:site_name/plans', constraints: { site_name: /[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+/ }
```

From the [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

> By default, dynamic segments don't accept dots - this is because the
>   dot is used as a separator for formatted routes. If you need to use a
>   dot within a dynamic segment, add a constraint that overrides this –
>   for example, id: /[^/]+/ allows anything except a slash.

Comment: My routes are generated routes using `resources`. Is the constraint still possible?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the accepted answer (adding a constraint that allows dots) unfortunately breaks your format.  For example, if you want to support both http://example.com/sites/1-blau.de and http://example.com/sites/1-blau.de.json, the second will not be handled by rails as format: json.  The  :site_name will be the entire 1-blau.de.json.  Uri encoding the dot as %2E gets handled differently by different browsers (Chrome will resolve %2E as a '.' whereas Firefox will keep it as %2E).

Comment: Thanks, I think it is a valid argument, and in such case I can only set contentType to `application/json` to avoid this.